# Clarifying with notation

Tags: graph-theory, optimization, machine-learning

I try to implement this [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1903.03894v1.pdf). It's about an instrument that provides explanations on how the Graph Neural Network makes its prediction.

Reading  this, I got the clear understanding of author idea but I can't understand the five formula $$ min_M{-\sum_{c=1}^C\mathbb{1}[y=c]log_{P_\Phi}(Y=y|G = A_S \odot \sigma(M), X=X_S)} $$, because I have no idea what $\mathbb{1}[y=c]$ term means and, therefor, from where came y. Is it an assigning or maybe it means the labeled sample?

Can anyone explain please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$[y=c]$ is an Iverson bracket: it evaluates to $1$ when $y=c$ and to $0$ otherwise. Its use here is not a good example of the notation: it would have been better written as $$min_M{-\sum_{y=1}^C\mathbb{1}log_{P_\Phi}(Y=y|G = A_S \odot \sigma(M), X=X_S)}$$

The bold $\mathbb{1}$ is probably a vector filled with $1$ or an identity matrix, but I haven't studied the paper in enough detail to figure out its dimensions.

Comment: In the original work 1 is denoted with blackboard bold font, with wich usually is denoted a space of real values R, vectors usually is denoted with just bold font. And vector or identity matrix doesn't have any sense, because we just get the sum of all probabilities.